Rmarkdown to pdf fails to render, giving LaTeX Error: Command \numberwithin undefined. Has anyone seen this problem and solved it?
I can no longer use RMarkdown to render pdfs.   Rmarkdown continues to render to HTML and Word.  I am working in Windows 11 and RStudio 2023.12.1 Build 402.
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22631)
Matrix products: default
locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.12       lubridate_1.9.2   digest_0.6.35     evaluate_0.21     zip_2.3.0
[6] stringi_1.7.12    rlang_1.1.3       cli_3.6.2         rstudioapi_0.16.0 generics_0.1.3
[11] openxlsx_4.2.5.2  rmarkdown_2.24    tools_4.2.2       tinytex_0.46      xfun_0.40
[16] yaml_2.3.8        fastmap_1.1.1     compiler_4.2.2    timechange_0.2.0  htmltools_0.5.8.1
[21] knitr_1.43
Last week I changed to the most recent version of RStudio before I noticed the problem.   However reinstalling the previous version of RStudio did not resolve the problem.   A check of the error message using ChatGPT4.0 suggested that the Latex package amsmath might need to be included. When I included options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE) in my Rmd file, no missing LaTex packages are identified.   The \numberwithin has to do with numbering of equations, text
The problem occurs any Rmd file, not just my production file--e.g. with the example Rmd file included with RStudio, I get the error message with this Rmd file when I knit to PDF:
---
title: "Test2"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)

R Markdown
summary(cars)

Including Plots
plot(pressure)




